# How to enable multiple selection with Ctrl for TreeViewer

Tags: java, treeview, eclipse-rcp, jface

I need to add multi-selection functionality to the project I am working on.
Up to now `SelectionChangedlistener` is used but that one has no option for multi-selection.

Is there any listener type that supports Ctrl-click selection that I could add in here?

That would be my best option currently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable multi-selection, Create the tree viewer with the `SWT.MULTI` style flag,

For example:

```
TreeViewer viewer = new TreeViewer( parent, SWT.MULTI );
```

The `ISelectionChangedListener` will be notified on single-selection as well as multi-selection. The selected elements are held in `SelectionChangedEvent::getSelection`.

See the code below for an example of a selection listener that extracts all selected elements:

```
ISelectionChangedListener listener = new ISelectionChangedListener() {
  @Override
  public void selectionChanged( SelectionChangedEvent event ) {
    IStructuredSelection selection = ( IStructuredSelection )event.getSelection();
    List<?> selectedElements = selection.toList();
  }
};
```

If you are targeting RCP platforms of version 4.8 and later only, you can also use `event.getStructuredSelection()` and spare yourself the cast. For example:

```
ISelectionChangedListener listener = new ISelectionChangedListener() {
  @Override
  public void selectionChanged( SelectionChangedEvent event ) {
    IStructuredSelection selection = event.getStructuredSelection();
    List<?> selectedElements = selection.toList();
  }
};
```

Comment: Yes, but how do i set the ctrl key as the deciding factor in this context?
I mean so that the selection actually happens

Comment: @MadalinBranea Once SWT.MULTI is used Ctrl+Click should work (unless you are using macOS when it is Cmd+Click)